# How to replace contents of arraylist with the contents of another arraylist?

Tags: java, oop, arraylist

I want to replace the contents of one arraylist with the contents of another completely.
For instance,

```
ArrayList<String> old = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> newlist = new ArrayList<String>();
old.add("Hi");
old.add("World");
newlist.add("League")
newlist.add("OfLegends"):
old = newlist;
```

When I try that, it does this odd behavior where the arraylist's size doubles with more elements. I don't want an arraylist twice the size of the original arraylist, I just want the old arraylist to be overriden with the new arraylist, where the contents of old and new arraylist are identical. Is there a way to do this without some sort of loop, or is that my only option? Thank you and pleae

Comment: When I tried it, it did replace it.

Comment: `newlist.add("OfLegends"):` should be a `;` :)

Comment: Also a semicolon after `newlist.add("League")`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
old.clear(); 
old.addAll(newList);
```

This will clear the old list and add copies of the references from newList to the old list. If you make changes to the old list, the new list will stay unaffected (and vice versa) .

Note as your code stands, you are setting the old list to the same object reference as the new list. Changing one of those lists (with an `add()` or `remove()`) will change the other as they share the same underlying object.

Comment: it uses `System.arraycopy` which is a native method

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following:

```
ArrayList<String> old = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> newList = new ArrayList<String>();
old.add("Hi");
old.add("World");
newList.add("League");
newList.add("OfLegends");
System.out.println(old.toString());
old = newList;
System.out.println(old.toString());
System.out.println(newList.toString());
```

And my output was :

```
[Hi, World]
[League, OfLegends]
[League, OfLegends]
```

So it seems like your code is working.

Comment: This is incorrect, `old` is just a reference to `newList` and not a true copy. Try modifying new, old will magically change as well.

Answer (score 0):

This is the constructor you’re looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList(java.util.Collection)

> `public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c)`
>
> Constructs a list containing the elements of the specified collection, in the order they are returned by the collection's iterator.